# How to assign a name to a window?

Tags: python

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
def moving_window(x, length, step=1):
    streams = it.tee(x, length)
    return zip(*[it.islice(stream, i, None, step+1) for stream, i in zip( streams,it.count(step=step))])
x_=list(moving_window(x,3))
x_=np.asarray(x_)
print(x_)
```

The output of this code is as follows:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [3 4 5]
 [5 6 7]
 [7 8 9]]
```

I want the output to be as follows:

```
a1 = [1 2 3]
a2 = [3 4 5]
a3 = [5 6 7]
a4 = [7 8 9]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; question has nothing to do with `machine-learning`, `jupyter-notebook`, or `classification` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import itertools as it
import numpy as np

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
def moving_window(x, length, step=1):
    streams = it.tee(x, length)
    return zip(*[it.islice(stream, i, None, step+1) for stream, i in zip( streams,it.count(step=step))])
x_=list(moving_window(x,3))

for i in range(len(x_)):
    globals()['a'+str(i)] = list(x_[i])

print(a0)
print(a1)
print(a2)
print(a3)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[3, 4, 5]
[5, 6, 7]
[7, 8, 9]
```

my code base on len `x_` can change.
see if your input like this `x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]` your output like this:

```
print(a0)
print(a1)
print(a2)
print(a3)
print(a4)
```

```
[1, 2, 3]
[3, 4, 5]
[5, 6, 7]
[7, 8, 9]
[9, 10, 11]
```

Comment: You're in the global namespace, so your `locals()` is actually `globals()`. If you tried this with actual locals, it wouldn't work.

Comment: @khelwood, yes you say right, thank you, I edit the code block, if you have any advice I'm happy

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would suggest not using the output format you would like. As leaving the array as an array and accessing each sub-array as below would be significantly better structured code and would avoid lots of repetition.

```py
x_[0] # [1 2 3]
x_[1] # [4 5 6]
# .. etc
```

However, if you really want the output in separate variables, you can do the following

```py
a1 = x_[0]
a2 = x_[1]
a3 = x_[2]
a4 = x_[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

````
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
def moving_window(x, length, step=1):
    streams = it.tee(x, length)
    return zip(*[it.islice(stream, i, None, step+2) for stream, i in zip( streams,it.count(step=step))])
x_=list(moving_window(x,6))

for i in range(len(x_)):
    globals()['a'+str(i)] = list(x_[i])
    print(x_[i])

def mean(dataset):
    return sum(dataset) / len(dataset)
for i in range(len(x_)):
    globals()['a'+str(i)] = list(x_[i])
    a=mean(x_[i])
    print(a)```

**this is my code**
this is my output:
3.5
6.5

**My output of this code is as follows**

3.5

6.5

**I want to write a code that takes these numbers and stores them in a directory.
This data will be more and this is an example.
I think a floating value should be defined .**

An example of what I want:
in table:

a1  3.5

a2  6.5

a3   ...

a4   ...

.

.

.
````